# Can you create TRIGGER that is run if a TABLE is DROPPED?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is is possible to create a TRIGGER that can detect if a TABLE is DROPPED using MySQL 5.6.10?

I have a many databases with the same table and I want to detect if and when a that table is either updated or dropped and replaced.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The three trigger events are INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE, with options for BEFORE and AFTER.

There's no trigger for DROP.

The same is true for MySQL 5.7 and 8.0.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: That's what I thought.